# How to convert a type named "LIstEntries" to iterable<ListEntries>

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, types, iterable

I am trying to create a search function in my app and I am getting many issues due to type conversions. The search is to be done in a ListView of many entries and for that I created a class named ListEntries.

This is the code of the screen that makes the search in this list of Entries:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'listentries.dart';

class searchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String searchTerm;
  searchScreen({this.searchTerm});

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => new _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<searchScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final widgetElements = new ListEntries(); // From listentries.dart
    var searchedItems = widgetElements;

    String entry;

    entry = searchedItems.toString();

    final duplicateItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");
    var items = List<String>();

    void filterSearchResults(String query) {
      List<ListEntries> dummySearchList = List<ListEntries>();

      dummySearchList.addAll(searchedItems);
      if (query.isNotEmpty) {
        List<ListEntries> dummyListData = List<ListEntries>();
        dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
          if (item.contains(query)) {
            dummyListData.add(item);
          }
        });
        setState(() {
          items.clear();
          items.addAll(dummyListData);
        });
        return;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          items.clear();
          items.addAll(duplicateItems);
        });
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          "Search your term",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    filterSearchResults(value);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Search',
                      hintText: 'Search your term',
                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
                )),
            Expanded(
              child: searchedItems,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: bannerAd,
    );
  }
}
```

The Type LisEntries is defined in this other file (listentries.dart):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'destination.dart';
import 'package:insurance_dictionary/facebook_code.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class ListEntries extends StatefulWidget {
  ListEntries({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ListEntriesState createState() => ListEntriesState();
}

class ListEntriesState extends State<ListEntries> {
  bool isFirstUse = true;
  int numUses = 0;
  int cycle = 5;
  //static FutureBuilder<String> listOfEntries;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future:
                DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var entries = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              //listOfEntries = entries;
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  var entrada = entries[index];
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 60,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if ((isFirstUse) || (numUses % cycle == 0)) {
                          loadInterstitialAd();
                          sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
                          showInterstitialAd();
                          isFirstUse = false;
                          numUses++;
                        } else {
                          numUses++;
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Destination(
                                entry: entrada['Entry'],
                                definition: entrada['Definition'],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      color: Colors.blue[900],
                      child: Text(
                        entrada['Entry'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: entries == null ? 0 : entries.length,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The errors that I am getting are located in these steps in the search_entries.dart file:

```
dummySearchList.addAll(searchedItems);

items.addAll(dummyListData);
```

Both errors say: "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'."

There is another error in this step:

```
 if (item.contains(query)) {...}
```

In this case, the error says: "The method 'contains' isn't defined for the type 'ListEntries'."

I have been fighting with this kind of errors for several days.  Could you give a good advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See your declarations:

```
List<ListEntries> dummyListData = List<ListEntries>();
var items = List<String>();
```

Both of them are a `List` type but store different types: `String` and `ListEntries`

For second error, same problem with types. `ListEntries` is not an `Iterable` type but a Widget.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are calling `.contains` directly on `item` which is an object of type (class) `ListEntries`. The method `.contains` should be used on an iterable. You can define any `Iterable` inside `ListEntries` and them call `.contains` in it:

```
item.myIterable.contains(query)
```

Comment: Bro, `constains` method is for any of these classes: String, iterable, set

Comment: @pedropimont:  Could you detail a little more about how to define a method .contains for ListEntries?  I'm trying to figure out and still not getting it,  - Thanks. ;)

Comment: you can define it like you define any other function inside of a class. But thats not the problem. the variable 'item' which you are trying to call the function 'contains' is a custom object of type ListEntries that you created, it doesn't make sense to use .contains in it. This method .contains is a method from the Iterable class (which is a built-in class that Strings and Lists belong to) and ListEntries isn't neither of those objects. You can use .contains in Strings/Lists, but the variable 'item' is a ListEntrie object defined by you. Naming it like a list doesnt make it one. Its a Widget